# Django autenticação

Tags: python, django, autenticação, auth

boa tarde!

Estou iniciando na programação WEB e acabei esbarrando num problema com o Django no quesito autenticação.
Já li toda a documentação que fala sobre Auth Customizados do Django mas ainda não encontrei uma solução.
Com base no model abaixo criei um form para inclusão de usuários no sistema e está funcionando normalmente, porém não consigo sair desse ponto para autenticar utilizando o model abaixo, pois pretendo relacionar campos dessa tabela posteriormente em outras funcionalidades do sistema.

**Models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    ATIVO_CHOICES=[("ATIVO","ATIVO"),("INATIVO","INATIVO")]
    BLOQUEADO_CHOICES=[("BLOQUEADO","BLOQUEADO"),("DESBLOQUEADO","DESBLOQUEADO")]


    user_cod = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_nome = models.CharField("Nome Completo",max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    user_email = models.EmailField("Email",unique=True, blank=False)
    user_ativo = models.CharField("Situação",max_length=25,choices=ATIVO_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    user_bloqueado = models.CharField("Bloqueado?",max_length=25,choices=BLOQUEADO_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)
    user_cpf = models.CharField("CPF",max_length=11, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, validators=[validate_CPF])
    user_senha = models.CharField("Senha",max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)



    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
```

**Forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'user_senha': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

**views.py**

```
def user_create(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():        
            cd = form.cleaned_data
             # assert False
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userlist')
```

Eu queria continuar utilizando essa tela dessa maneira, porém agora preciso autenticar usuários criados e armazenados nessa base de dados sem afetar esse código.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente seja bem vindo ao mundo web com Django! gostaria de apontar algumas coisas que você pode fazer para atingir o que você deseja, primeiro você precisa [reescrever](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) o método `save` do seu modelo `User` porque ele está salvando a senha em puro texto no banco de dados e isso não é o recomendável,para resolver isso existe [algumas formas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) que basicamente é aproveita o modelo `User` do Django ou implementar o método `save()` utilizando algum tipo de criptografia. Caso você escolha implementar o metodo `save()` você precisa redireciona-los para a tela de login quando o usuário não estiver logado, essa lógica vai ficar na `view`, na sua implementação você apenas ta verificando se o formulário é válido e não se o usuário que tentou logar realmente existe no seu banco de dados ou seja o formulário pode está validado mas o usuário pode não existir.

um exemplo de como seria isso na sua `view`

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():        
            name = form.cleaned_data['user_nome']
            senha = form.cleaned_data['user_senha']
            user = User.objects.filter(user_nome=name,user_senha=senha)
            if user is not None:
                # usuário autenticado
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/userlist')
            else: 
                # usuário não existe
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/userlist')
```

Pra saber mais sobre como fazer queries olhe na [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)